# Using Stream as a substitute for loop

Tags: scala

```
scala> val s = for(i <- (1 to 10).toStream) yield { println(i); i }
1
s: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> s.take(8).toList
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
res15: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)

scala> s.take(8).toList
res16: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

Looks like Scala is storing stream values in memory to optimize access. Which means that `Stream` can't be used as a substitute for imperative loop as it will allocate memory. Things like `(for(i <- (1 to 1000000).toStream, j <- (1 to 1000000).toStream) yield ...).reduceLeft(...)` will fail because of memory. Was it wrong idea to use streams this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `Iterator` instead of `Stream` if you want a loop-like collection construct.  `Stream` is specifically for when you want to store past results.  If you don't, then, for instance:

```
scala> Iterator.from(1).map(x => x*x).take(10).sum
res23: Int = 385
```

Methods `continually`, `iterate`, and `tabulate` are among the more useful ones in this regard (in the `Iterator` companion object).